# Fail to install tensorflow from source in ubuntu

Tags: tensorflow

My story is:
First, I install tensorflow by pip first, but it can not work in SSE4.2.
Then I try to install it from source. My environment is:
1) newly installed ubuntu.
2) follow the instruction from tensorflow
3) ./Configure:

```
Please specify the location of python. [Default is /usr/bin/python]: **enter**
Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is -march=native]: **enter**
Do you wish to use jemalloc as the malloc implementation? [Y/n] **N**
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Google Cloud Platform support? [y/N] **N**
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Hadoop File System support? [y/N]
No Hadoop File System support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with the XLA just-in-time compiler (experimental)? [y/N]
Found possible Python library paths:
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages] **enter**
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with OpenCL support? [y/N] **N**
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N] **N**
```

However, I got the following questions after importing tensorflow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
ImportError: cannot import name pywrap_tensorflow


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Could you help me point what is my mistake here? Many thanks!

Comment: can you come out of git folder and try importing tensorflow (from some different folder)?

Comment: @hars many thanks for your helps! I just go back to pip install without using SSE4.2, since I can do some experiment quickly. So I will try it later.